# how to move one activity to another activity in android

Tags: database, android-intent

enter code here 
package com.example.registration;
I am trying to move from one activity to another if the user clicks The Button. The Linear layout is set to clikable. The application gets loaded. But when the onClick is not performed for moving on to the next activity.My Code Below

Answer (score 0):

```
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
.....
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener  {
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ....
    findViewById(R.id.myButtonId).setOnClickListener(this);
}
...
public void onClick(View view) {
    .. // check view.getId()
     //start another activity
     Intent intent = new Intent(this, AnotherActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     ...
}
```